# How to disable caching in Ionic 2

Tags: http, get, ionic2

How to disable data caching in Ionic 2 ! As in previous version of Ionic was just by putting cache-view="false" ,, then what can be used instead ?

I need to disable caching in the particular view since i got problem of loading the same data from database after using http get!